# WP7 - ListPicker in StackPanel in ScrollViewer

Tags: windows-phone-7, scrollviewer, stackpanel, listpicker

Just started with developing for WP7 and came across the following. I have a pivot application with a few pivotitems. On the first pivotitem (see code below) I want to be able to adjust a lot of settings. For this question all items to be set are called 'TextBox' and the choice in the ListPicker is either A,B or C.

Now if I do NOT use the ScrollViewer and I tap any of the listpickers I get to see all three options BUT I can not scroll through all listpickers.

If I DO use the ScrollViewer, I CAN see all listpickers but only the top one (that's visible) will expand and give me the options A,B and C, they others stay collapsed.

How can I get every listpicker to expand and show me the avaiable options AND be able to scroll to every listpicker on the page?

PS In code below copy the stackpanel between start and end about 15 times.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
            <controls:PivotItem Header="blabla">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,36,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="Width">

// start
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Width="80"  TextAlignment="Right" Margin="10,22,20,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
                        <toolkit:ListPicker Margin="0" Width="275">
                            <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="A"/>
                            <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="B"/>
                            <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="C"/>
                        </toolkit:ListPicker>
                    </StackPanel>

// end - copy/paste code code between start and end about 15 times right here


                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </controls:PivotItem>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is, apparently, a common issue with `Listpicker` and `ScrollViewer`. You can find a workaround [here](http://attowares.com/blog/2011/08/23/listpicker-inside-scrollviewer-wp7-toolkit-mango/)

Answer (score 2):

Should anybody stumble upon this, this has been fixed since the november 2011 release of the wP7 silverlight toolkit.